# Unable to rename a group folder in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide

I added a new group from selection today in Xcode containing several files. For some reason, this has consisted for a while, I am unable to name or rename the group folder.

Has this happened to anyone else before, if so have you come across a fix?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What have you tried to do in order to rename it?

The contextual menu (right click) does not provide a rename option. Therefore I either

1. Select the group
2. Hit return which selects it for editing

OR

1. Select the group
2. After a short delay (long enough to not count as a double click) click it again

Comment: It now works with the both methods you supplied. I was just double clicking on the label and presuming that it was going to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Renaming groups seems to be finicky at times.  Every so often I have to try a number of times to get into editing mode.  So try a few times if it's not going with one of these methods.

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes it happens.

Workaround:

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Launch Xcode.
   *Tada*

Comment: it's 2019 and we're still turning it off and turning it back on again. good to know some things never change.

Comment: That did not work for me.  Still testing code (and only testing code) cannot find the code in the renamed directory

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that has my issue: Check your files in Finder. I had a folder that was already using that name. Delete that folder and it will allow you to change name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename the folder probably because that folder already exists in that directory.

**To solve it:**

1. Select the folder you want to rename, press the right button, press show in finder.
2. Delete the folder(s) that already have the name you want.
3. Go to Xcode and try again.
4. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Some times its not related to xcode, its finder problem, because directory still exists and finder doesn't show that, you can see directory exists by entering ls in terminal.

How to solve this?

Open terminal and navigate to parent directory of desired directory : cd ~/../parent or just right click parent directory and choose New Terminal at Folder
Remove desired directory : rm -rf MyGroup
Now you can try to create your group with MyGroup name.